# Form submitting by jconfirm box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I wanna give the confirmation box i.e. `jconfirm()` before submitting the form .if user clicks yes, then  form should be submitted , if user clicks no then `retrun false`.i did as below

```
 jConfirm('Do you', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
             if(r){
        $("#person-form").submit();
       }})

      return false;
```

but the form is not submitting, if i remove `return false;` , the jconfirm box doesnt stay until we click on yes or no button

UPDATE: I solved it like this:

```
var pcount = 1;
$('form').submit(function(e){ 
  if(pcount == 1) { 
    if(($("#SecondPrime").val() == 1) && ($("#Person_PersonTypeCode").val() == 'ADULT')) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      jConfirm("Do you wanna say ?", "confirmation", function(result){ 
        if(result) { pcount++; } 
        else { 
          pcount++;
          $('form').submit(); 
        } 
      }); 
    } 
  } 
});
```

Comment: In my case i used `if(r == true)`

Comment: thank you bro, i tried but this didnt work

Comment: then see your browser console, if any error can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel the submit event and submit yourself using the event-handler free DOM submit:

NOTE: This can ONLY be done if there is nothing called `name="submit"` in the form

```
$("#person-form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventdefault(); // stop submission
  jConfirm('Do you', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    if (r) {
      $("#person-form")[0].submit(); // DOM form
    }
  });
});
```

UPDATE: I gave up figuring out what your jConfirm needed. The code [here](http://flwebsites.biz/jConfirm/) needs an element on the page to work.

```
  $("someSelector").jConfirm(....)
```

If you want your jConfirm to work, please post WHICH jConfirm you use, which version (old version does not work with jQuery1.9+ wherease jConfirm v2 likely does.

In the meantime here is a version using [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#person-form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      content: 'It will submit!',

      buttons: {
        confirm: function() {
          $("#person-form")[0].submit(); // DOM form
        },
        cancel: function() {
          $.alert('Canceled!');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.0/jquery-confirm.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<form id="person-form" action="javascript:alert('submitted')">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That is not enough information - errors in console? On server?

Comment: it is not giving any alert just form is submitting,if I use like as `$("#person-form").on("submit", function(e) {
    alert('rajesh')
      e.preventdefault(); // stop submission
      jConfirm('Do you', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
        if (r) {
         alert('ranjith')
          $("#person-form")[0].submit(); // DOM form
        }
      });
    });` the first alert is raising but the second jconfirm is not raising and form is submitting

Comment: Errors in the console?

Comment: just form is submitting rather than raising jconfirm,so there are no errors in the console

Comment: You need to capture the console log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139919/discussion-between-crajesh-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I dont know how to capture the console log , will u please explain

Comment: Chrome - F12 - red button in left corner of console. Also make a [mcve] in the question using the `<>` button

Comment: Please see my update. I have wasted quite a bit of time because you did not produce enough code to show what plugin you use and also not posted your form

Comment: Sorry sir,for making you to waste your time and thank you sir,for providing the brief explanation and I will try this and hope I will resolve my issue with this explanation, I will post the status of issue after I try this

Comment: yes sir ,  i find out the problem that from ur first answer, the form is submitting looply while i click on ok button on jconfirm and it is repeating as form submits jconfirm raises if i click ok on jconfirm and the form submits again and it repeats but the form is not submitting to store values in db as it is cycling at validation and for that you have suggestion sir..?

Comment: I have no idea since I do not know jConfirm. PLEASE post a working example or use the second code I suggested

Comment: I have just resolved as  `var pcount = 1;
   $('form').submit(function(e){
                      
    if(pcount == 1)
    {
     

     if(($("#SecondPrime").val() == 1) && ($("#Person_PersonTypeCode").val() == 'ADULT'))
       {
        e.preventDefault();
           jConfirm("Do you wanna say ?", "confirmation", function(result){
              if(result)
              {
               pcount++;
              }
              else
              {
               pcount++;
            $('form').submit();
              }
           });
     }
       
    }
    }); `

Comment: That does not make much sense.

Comment: If you had done what I suggested and not called .submit() but instead [0].submit() it would not be necessary to use a flag

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
jConfirm('Do you', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
   if(!r){
       return;
   }else {
     $("#person-form").submit();
  }
});
```

Or else you can use below this for make custom confirm box 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: Remove `return false;` at the end.

Comment: it I remove `return false;` , the confirm box doesnt stays until i click yes or no

Comment: Why return on the !r? that is plain silly - also it is a callback. You cannot return anything in a callback

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#person-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   jConfirm('Do you', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
     if(r == true)
     {
        $('#person-form').submit();
     }
     else
     { /*Handle else case here*/ }
    });
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan The above solution similar to your answer i guess!

Comment: I submit the DOM form

Comment: this too dont work , as the form submits , jconfirm raises and if i click ok on jconfirm the form again submits and the jconfirm raises and it repeats than submitting the form to store the data into db